# Choppy videos and animations since 18.04

Tags: video

Since upgrading from 17.10 to 18.04 my video streaming and amimations have become choppy. Running glxgears it can be seen that the animation stops and then starts again every 3 seconds or so. The same with video streaming, the picture stutters every 3 seconds.  This happens using the Intel GPU and also using the nVidia GPU via Bumblebee (Optirun).

Does anybody have an idea what could be causing this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I fixed the problem by removing nvidia-settings and disabling the gnome extension "NVIDIA GPU Stats Tool".

Comment: Why would someone have to uninstall `nvidia-settings`?

Comment: I don't have GPU stats gnome extension listed  in  the gnome-tweak-tool > extensions, I must not have it

Answer (score 0):

As I understand it, nVidia bumblebee was replaced by nVidia Prime. So try:

`sudo apt install nvidia-settings nvidia-prime` (and it should uninstall bumblebee)
Then restart and open nvidia settings and make sure you pick nVidia card (not intel) and restart again.